# To change the citation/Reference style

Tags: bibliographies

I want to change the citation/Reference style in my article. So far I follow the following style:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
    \bibitem{ii} Andrew, B., \textit{An introduction to p-adic numbers and p-adic analysis}, URL:https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/ $\sim$ajb.
    \bibitem{kj} Bachman, G., \textit{Introduction to p-adic numbers and valuation theory}, Academic Press, \textbf{1964}.
    \bibitem{hj}Conrad, K., \textit{Infinite series in p- adic fields},\\ 
    URL:https://www.math.uconn.edu/$ \sim$kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf
    \bibitem{citekey} Dragovich, B., Khrennikov, A.Y., Kozyrev, S.V. et al. P-Adic Num Ultrametr Anal Appl (2009) 1: 1. https://doi.org/10.1134/S2070046609010014
    \bibitem{brancho-1} Dragovich, B., Power series everywhere convergent on $\mathbb{R}$ and all $\mathbb{Q}_p$, J. Math. Phys., \textbf{1993}.
    \bibitem{brancho-2} Dragovich, B., \textit{On some p-adic series with factorials}, arXiv preprint math-ph/0402050, \textbf{2004}.
    \bibitem{jgh} Gouvea, F. Q., p-adic numbers : An introduction, 2nd Edition, Springer-Verlag, \textbf{1997}.
    \bibitem{j}Katok, S., \textit{p-adic analysis compared with real}, American Mathematical Society, \textbf{2007}.
    \bibitem{abc} Koblitz, N., \text{p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-functions}, Springer, \textbf{1984}.
    \bibitem{jhg} Robert, A. M., \textit{A course in p-adic analysis}, Springer-Verlag, \textbf{2000}.
     \bibitem{schi-1}   W. H. Schikhof, \textit{Ultrametric Calculus} Cambridge U.P., Cambridge, \textbf{1984}..
\end{thebibliography}
```

This produces the following style both in **text part (citation part)** (see the highlighted parts) :

[image]

And in the **Reference part**, it looks like (see the highlighted parts):

[image]

But I want the following style both in citation part and in Reference part:

[image]

That is I want to display few letter of Authors name rather than numerical numbers $1,2,3,...$

Any help doing such Reference as in the last image.

**Edit:**

How to display the following style (where not only the paper but also the proposition or theorem will be mentioned):

[image]

Comment: If you generate your bibliography manually, you also have to specify the label manually (unless you want simple numbers). Use the optional argument of `\bibitem` to give the label: `\bibitem[An]{ii} Andrew, B., ...`, `\bibitem[Ba]{kj} Bachman, G.,` etc. etc. Don't forget to replace the `10` in `\begin{thebibliography}{10}` with the actual longest label in your bibliography: e.g. `\begin{thebibliography}{Kat~2}`.

Comment: @moewe, Thanks. How to cite now ? I use `\cite{}`

Comment: @moewe, Yes, I got it. Thanks

Comment: @moewe, I have a related  question. Please see the last part (Edit) of my question. I want to display (or cite) not only the paper but also the exact Proposition or Theorem separated by a 'comma' after the paper name. How to do that ? Any help please

Comment: Normally, `\cite[Prop.~1.1]{kj}` (i.e. `\cite[<pinpoint>]{<entry key>}`) should work. But this might depend on citations packages you load, which you haven't shared with us so far.

Comment: @moewe,  Very nice.Thank you very much. It worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are generating your bibliography manually, you really have to do everything in the bibliography manually. This includes giving the desired citation labels if they are not numeric.

The citation label can be given in the optional argument to `\bibitem`: `\bibitem[<citation label>]{<cite key>}`. You should then give the longes citation label in the mandatory argument of `thebibliography` (in the example below the longest label is `Dr~3`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{brancho-1}

\cite[Prop.~1.5.8]{ii}

\begin{thebibliography}{Dr~3}
  \bibitem[An]{ii} Andrew, B., \textit{An introduction to p-adic numbers and p-adic analysis},
    URL: \url{https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb}.
  \bibitem[Ba]{kj} Bachman, G., \textit{Introduction to p-adic numbers and valuation theory},
    Academic Press, \textbf{1964}.
  \bibitem[Co]{hj}Conrad, K., \textit{Infinite series in p-adic fields},
    URL: \url{https://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf}
  \bibitem[Dr~1]{citekey} Dragovich, B., Khrennikov, A.Y., Kozyrev, S.V. et al.
    P-Adic Num Ultrametr Anal Appl (2009) 1: 1. \url{https://doi.org/10.1134/S2070046609010014}
  \bibitem[Dr~2]{brancho-1} Dragovich, B., Power series everywhere convergent
    on~$\mathbb{R}$ and all~$\mathbb{Q}_p$, J. Math. Phys., \textbf{1993}.
  \bibitem[Dr~3]{brancho-2} Dragovich, B., \textit{On some p-adic series with factorials},
    arXiv preprint math-ph/0402050, \textbf{2004}.
  \bibitem[Go]{jgh} Gouvea, F. Q., p-adic numbers: An introduction,
    2nd Edition, Springer-Verlag, \textbf{1997}.
  \bibitem[Ka]{j}Katok, S., \textit{p-adic analysis compared with real},
    American Mathematical Society, \textbf{2007}.
  \bibitem[Ko]{abc} Koblitz, N., \textit{p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-functions},
    Springer, \textbf{1984}.
  \bibitem[Ro]{jhg} Robert, A. M., \textit{A course in p-adic analysis},
    Springer-Verlag, \textbf{2000}.
  \bibitem[Sc]{schi-1} Schikhof, W. H. , \textit{Ultrametric Calculus},
    Cambridge U.P., Cambridge, \textbf{1984}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: [An, Prop. 1.5.8]//[An] Andrew, B., An introduction to p-adic numbers and p-adic analysis, URL: https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb.]

Specific references to theorems, propositions, lemmas etc. can be given via the optional argument of `\cite`: `\cite[<pinpoint reference>]{<cite key>}`